# 36 eggs a day, is it legit?

Tags: muscle, muscle-gain, testosterone, eggs, cholesterol

I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=SQ6xtn1aiP0)
about Vince Gironda's 36 egg a day diet in which it states that the diet is similar to taking a cycle a dianabol. The basics of this idea is that eating dozens of eggs per day would result in higher testosterone levels from 2 sources. The first reason from having higher cholesterol levels, would be cholesterol as a metabolic substrate of androgen and estradiol. The second reason comes from eggs possibly still having active hormones in them. Now I am sure that it might not be close to as effective as D-bol, but has anyone tried it? Does it seem to work? Is the reasoning behind the claim legit?

There's even a interesting [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1191862) that states that 35 eggs a day helped burn victims recover faster.

Answer (score 1):

A quick review of the literature indicates it might be plausible, although the effects are likely to be much more modest than an actual pharmacological intervention.

[Ketogenic diet and testosterone increase: Is the increased cholesterol intake responsible? To what extent and under what circumstances can there be benefits?](http://www.hormones.gr/pdf/04_1498_Santos_editorial.pdf) concludes:

> All things considered, Wilson’s study indirectly provides a solid
>   basis for further research into planning a dietary method for boosting
>   testosterone production in men

[Testosterone and cortisol in relationship to dietary nutrients and resistance exercise meanwhile](https://www.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/jappl.1997.82.1.49) concludes:

> Preexercise T[estosterone] was significantly positively correlated
>   with percent energy fat

So.... not quite as crazy as it first sounds, but still pretty crazy.